# RegEx HTML like inner expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match sth like html tags with regEx. It's sth like that:

```
Lorem <div class="sth">ipsum dolor <div class="another">sit amet, consectetur</div> adipiscing</div> elit
```

And my regular expression is:

```
/<\s*div[^>]*>(.*?)<\s*/\s*div>/g
```

But it should match first `<div class="sth">` with last `</div>` and second `<div class="another">` with first `</div>`. I want both expressions(one of them is inner and other one is outer). So I want to match the regular expressions like HTML does.

Here is the code page: https://www.regextester.com/111196

I'm using JavaScript as the programming language.

**EDIT**

I'm editing the question beacause of misunderstanding. I gave the expression for just understand it good. Actuall my regex is different:

```
/\*\*\*.*?\*\*\*.*?\*/\*\*.*?\*\*\*/g
```

And my text is:

```
Aenean ***life*** sed consectetur. ***Lorem*** ipsum dolor */**sit*** amet, consectetur */**adipiscing*** elit.

As you see ***${sth}*** is like the opening tag and */**${sth}*** is like the closing tag.
```

But when I put an expression into another, it confuses. I asked how can handle this situation.

Here is the demo: https://www.regextester.com/?fam=111201

Comment: Building such regex is very complex and is unmaintainable. Write your own parser.

Answer (score 0):

It's best not to rely on regular expression to parse HTML, as you will always encounter exceptions that will break your regex.

Instead, add your HTML code into a temp element, that will let you use query selectors to match your tags.

```js
let temp = document.createElement('div');
temp.innerHTML = 'Lorem <div class="sth">ipsum dolor <div class="another">sit amet, consectetur</div> adipiscing</div> elit';
divTags = temp.getElementsByTagName('div');

console.log(divTags[0].outerHTML);
```

Comment: I gave the example as sample and not trying to parse HTML